# Splunk: How to extract a field containing spaces at end

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, rex

I try to extract the value of a field that contains spaces. Apparently it is hard to find a regular expression for this case (even the question is if it is possible at all).

Example: `03 Container ID - ALL_ELIGIBLE_STG_RTAIN Offer Set ID`

From Above example, we  have to get the count  `Container ID - ALL_ELIGIBLE_STG_RTAIN`

I am Expecting like this.

| Container ID | Count |
| --- | --- |
| ALL_ELIGIBLE_STG_RTAIN | xxxx |

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Is `Container ID - ` string present in all events that your are interested in?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all container IDs are preceded by "Container ID - " then this command will extract them.

```
| rex "Container ID - (?<ContainerID>\S+)"
```